# Extract rsa.PrivateKey from openpgp.Entity

Tags: go, rsa

RSA has several key formats. Is there a way to extract a  PKCS 1 private key from a PGP key in golang?
Something lik this (it does not work):

```
var e *openpgp.Entity
e, err := openpgp.NewEntity("test11", "test", "test@test.com", nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

key, ok := e.PrivateKey.PrivateKey.(rsa.PrivateKey)
if !ok {
    // Here is the problem in this solution
    fmt.Printf("Assertation failed")
}

pkcs1PrivateKey := x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(&key)

privkey_pem := pem.EncodeToMemory(
    &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: pkcs1PrivateKey,
    },
)
fmt.Printf(string(privkey_pem))
```

Comment: if the assertion failed, what is the type? The docs say it's going to be one of `rsa|dsa|ecdsa`, so maybe you should type switch between those three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to `*rsa.PrivateKey` and call `MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key)`:

```
key, ok := e.PrivateKey.PrivateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
if !ok {
    // Here is the problem in this solution
    fmt.Printf("Assertation failed")
}

pkcs1PrivateKey := x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key)
```

But this will only make this bit of code work. In production code, you'll need to do a type switch like @Jimb mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is:

```
key, ok := e.PrivateKey.PrivateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
if !ok {
    fmt.Printf("Assertation failed")
}
```

This cast must be a pointer, then the code workes. A type cast is the productive solution: 
Thanks to @denis-bernard and @JimB!